# Setting React Context from api response

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga, react-context

I have an app where after login, user details are acquired and some user profiles will have a metric setting and others will have a non-metric (imperial).

I want to set a boolean (isMetric) in React Context as there are stateless components all over that need to reference it and I want to avoid passing an isMetric prop all through the component hierarchy.

I've been following the React 16 examples at https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html and so I have a `unit-context.js` of:

```
export const UnitContext = React.createContext({
  isMetric: true,
  toggleUnits: () => {},
});
```

and an `App.js` of

```
import { UnitContext } from './unit-context';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.toggleUnits = () => {
      this.setState(state => ({
        isMetric: !state.isMetric
      }));
    };

    this.state = {
      isMetric: true,
      toggleUnits: this.toggleUnits,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <UnitContext.Provider value={this.state}>
        < ... />
      </UnitContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

The above is the dynamic pattern that provides `toggleUnits` in the context itself so that state (context) can be set.

With the above pattern, I've confirmed that in my components I can access the isMetric value fine.

But I use redux-saga to handle api calls and it is retrieving the user's metric / non-metric setting.

Once I've acquired the user details, how can I set Context? (redux-saga seems to have it's own context aspect but I'm referring to React Context).

One option is to import the UnitContext with

`import { UnitContext } from '.unit-context';`

and then access the Consumer to get the state and thus the function. But I'm unsure how to reference what would normally be a Component in a redux-saga saga which is imperative code.

Alternatively, could I move the App state to redux? That seems odd and unsound to have a function in a redux store. I know that redux-saga provides a `select` method to access redux store via selectors and I have used that in the past.

**Update:**

As the context is provided by `<UnitContext.Provider value={this.state}>` then conceivably I could replace that **value** property setting with a redux store value instead of using local state.

Comment: The update you provided is very much the way to go :)

Comment: Thanks. I was reading/reviewing/thinking the new Context API then only stepping back did I realise that it's all in the "value" prop passed to the provider.